# How can I print a text, when a specific user role is logged in?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple members table in my mySQL database with the following fields: *memberID, username, password, role*.

I want to print a text, when a specific *role* is logged in. I tried it with the *username* and here it works very well:

```
  <?php if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'Barbara') : ?>
            <span>Hello Admin!</span>
       <?php endif; ?>
```

But when I try to do the same thing with the *role*, it is not printing anything.

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') : ?>
            <span>Hello Admin!</span>
       <?php endif; ?>
```

What could be the reason?

This is my login script:

```
<?php

require_once('includes/config.php');


if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: memberpage.php'); } 


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: memberpage.php');
        exit;

    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }

}


$title = 'Login';


require('layout/header.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: Can we have `var_dump($_SESSION);`?

Comment: Try doing a print_r($_SESSION); and check wether the role is actually set in the Session - And that it is "admin" (Beat me to it D4V1D ;) )

Comment: print_r($_SESSION) is doing this: Array ( [loggedin] => 1 [username] => Barbara)

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION): array(2) { ["loggedin"]=> bool(true) ["username"]=> string(9) "Barbara" }

Comment: how can I set the role in the session?

Comment: @fala This means that the "role" index is not even set in the session. You should make sure to set the Role index when the user logs in. That way, it will be persisted across the current session. Add your "login" script to your question, if you need help setting the role session.

Comment: @Jonas: I posted the script as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the User.php class with a new method to fetch the userData based on a username. You only need to use the username once pr. execution (unless you would like to load another users data )

Then updated the session setter to fetch the role data, and set it.

Best Jonas

---

Try and update your User.php file with this:

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{
    private $_db;
    private $_userData;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_userData = null;

        $this->_db = $db;
    }



    private function get_user_hash($username){  
        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            return $row['password'];
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }
    public function login($username,$password){
        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            return true;
        }   
    }

    public function getUserData($username = null)
    {
        if( is_null( $this->_userData ) && is_null( $username ) )
        {
          return null;
        }

        if( !is_null( $this->_userData ) && is_null( $username ) )
        {
            return $this->_userData;
        }

        if( !is_null($username) )
        {
            try {
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT username,role FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
                $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

                $this->_userData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                return $this->_userData;
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
            }
        }

    }

    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }
    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }       
    }

}
?>
```

And then, do like this:

```
<?php

    require_once('includes/config.php');


    if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: memberpage.php'); } 


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
            $userData = $user->getUserData( $username );
            // This is where you set your username session
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            // Set your role session here aswell

            $_SESSION['role'] = $userData->role; 

            header('Location: memberpage.php');
            exit;

        } else {
            $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
        }

    }


    $title = 'Login';


    require('layout/header.php'); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas, I copied your line in the code. Now if I log in I get this: array(3) { ["loggedin"]=> bool(true) ["username"]=> string(9) "Barbara" ["role"]=> NULL } But in my mySQL database the role is "admin". Why is it here NULL?

Comment: Well. Since i dont have all your codes, i do not know what data is filled into your $user variable. When you do the $user->login(), does the $user object then fill itself with the data from the database? If not, you will have to call the database to fetch the role from the user.

Comment: No it is a code from a tutorial. You can see the code here: https://github.com/daveismynamecom/loginregister

Comment: I tried to do this on my members page:     `$pdo =Database::connect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY memberID DESC';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo('<div>'.$row['role'].'</div>');}
    Database::disconnect();` This works very well

Comment: But when I do this, it is printing out nothing:       `$pdo = Database::connect();
$sql= 'SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '';
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
          
echo('<div>'.$row['role'].'</div>');
  
  }
    Database::disconnect();`

Comment: Thank you very much, I updated everything exactly like you said, but now my login page is white and empty. Must be some problem in the user.php

Comment: @fala - Could you add the following just under your <?php tag in config.php ? error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');    That should make sure that you see errors. when you have the error, please add it here :)

Comment: Yes I did updated the config.php, but the login page is still white

Comment: @fala Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80165/discussion-between-jonas-m-and-fala).

Answer (score 1):

you try below code

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['name']='urname';
$_SESSION['role']='admin';
if($_SESSION['role']=='admin')
{?>
<span>your logged as a admin</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your session is just storing the username not the role, you'll need to load the role from the database i.e.

```
<?php
  $rUserInfo=mysql_query("select * from members where username='".addslashes($_SESSION['username'])."'");
  if($aUserInfo=mysql_fetch_array($rUserInfo))
  {
    if($aUserInfo['role']=='admin')
    { 
?>
        <span>Hello Admin!</span>
<?php  
    }
}
?>
```